# ValueError: could not convert string to float with a specific file name

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to build a CNN using my own data set.

In the data pre-processing stage , I made a list `img_data_list` to store all the images which I would store in a numpy array later.

```
img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
```

However, I am now getting the following error :

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: s3_10-s416_10.jpg`

I am using these kind of image names (`s3_10-s416_10.jpg` etc) for validation purposes at a later stage.

How to get rid of this error ?

Comment: Forgetting about python, how do you convert the string `s3_10-s416_10.jpg` to a real number?

Comment: why are you trying to change a name to a float ? i mean what are you willing to do with it? maybe we can find you a better idea

Answer (score 1):

You error means that you are trying to convert the string `"s3_10-s416_10.jpg"` to a floating point number.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: s3_10-s416_10.jpg
```

What you probably want to do is to read the image data in your files and convert to floating point numbers (`float32`). It seems that `img_data_list` contains file names, not the contents of those files.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `img_data_list` is simply a list of file names, i.e. strings. You can't convert that to a float, hence the error.

Instead you need to read the contents of those files which can be done using `np.fromfile()`:

```
import np

img_filenames = ['s3_10-s416_10.jpg', 's4_10-s416_10.jpg']        # for example
images = [np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32) for f in img_filenames]
```

This will give you a list of the image data read from the files as `float32`.

What you do with it from there is not clear. Nor is it clear why you need to convert to float32. There will be header data which you would probably need to interpret. Perhaps it would be better to use `scipy`:

```
from scipy import ndimage

images = [ndimage.imread(f) for f in img_filenames]

>>> type(images[0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> images[0].dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> images[0].astype(np.float32).dtype    # convert to 32 bit float if you must
dtype('float32')
```